# React-native-image-modal problem with IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ImageModal>

Tags: reactjs, image, types, modal-dialog, native

I am copying the example from https://github.com/dev-yakuza/react-native-image-modal#readme.

```
<ImageModal
        imageBackgroundColor="#000000"
        modalImageResizeMode="contain"
        modalImageStyle={{
          width: 250,
          height: 250,
        }}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/07/25/18/58/church-4363258_960_720.jpg',
        }}
      />
```

And I get this error in source line:

> Type '{ imageBackgroundColor: string; modalImageResizeMode: string;
> modalImageStyle: { width: number; height: number; }; source: { uri:
> string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{
> children?: ReactNode; }>'.   Property 'source' does not exist on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
> Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2322)

It seems that the prop is not correct

Answer (score 0):

little late for this, that code changed, this code works:

```
<ImageModal
        resizeMode="contain"
        imageBackgroundColor="#000000"
        style={{
          width: 250,
          height: 250,
        }}
        source={{
          uri: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/07/25/18/58/church-4363258_960_720.jpg",
        }}
      />
```